# Этот код JS не работает в мобильных браузерах (onclick)

Tags: javascript

Дамы и господа, подскажите ибо сбился я. Сайт-webприложение, на нем есть 4 вкладки, на каждую вкладку повешано событие onclick. все летает и на desktop'e и на мобильном tap'ая - идет переключение по вкладкам. Фрагмент кода:

```
tab_1.onclick = f1;
tab_2.onclick = f2;
tab_3.onclick = f3;

function f1(){
    localStorage.setItem('tab', 1);
    field_1.style.display = 'block';
    field_2.style.display = 'none';
    field_3.style.display = 'none';
};
```

В одной из вкладок список из блоков, ожидая что кликнув на один из, блок развернется и станет доступно видео, так все отлично работает на desktop'е, но на смартофне ни в какую

```
wrapper.onclick = click;

function click(event) {

  if (event.target.classList.contains('video_paragraph')) {
    if (!event.path[1].children[1].classList.contains("opened_video")) {
      event.path[1].children[1].classList.add("opened_video");
    }
    else {
      event.path[1].children[1].classList.remove("opened_video");
    }
  }
}
```

Просветите гуру, может что то чем то можно заменить, дабы добиться желаемого, на мой взгляд две идентичные технологии, но не работает одна из них..

UPD:

прикрепляю HTML

```
<div class="sports_day_wrappper<?=$extra_class?> <?=$active_day?>">
 <p class="video_paragraph"><?=$one_day[0]?></p>
 <iframe width="300" height="170" src="<?=$one_day[1]?>" title="111" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

UPD n SUCCESS

Умные люди подсказали, что метод которым я решал `event.path[1]` не является стандартным, и вместо него следует применять `composedPath()`

Таким образом решение, которое мне помогла выглядит так:

```
wrapper.onclick = click;
function click(MouseEvent) {

  if (MouseEvent.composedPath()[0].classList.contains('video_paragraph')) {
    if (!MouseEvent.composedPath()[1].children[1].classList.contains("opened_video")) {
      MouseEvent.composedPath()[1].children[1].classList.add("opened_video");
    }
    else {
      MouseEvent.composedPath()[1].children[1].classList.remove("opened_video");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Увидеть бы HTML ещё. Скорее всего проблема в том, что при клике `event.target` не `.video_paragraph` из-за чего условия не проходят.

Comment: @De.Minov 1. Как отследить этот момент будучи в мобраузере? 2. На Десктопе (отладка с эмуляцией моб устройства) все работает.

Comment: Скорее всего какой-нибудь элемент накладывается на элемент с кликом.... Задай всем элементам разные цвета и глянь в мобильном браузере не перекрывается ли этот элемент...

Comment: На крайней случай, можешь элементам с табами задать `position:relative; z-index:9999;` и проверь

Comment: @Air С табами как раз проблем нет, а вот тем вкладкам задал индекс 10(выше точно в проекте не было), но увы, не работает. Очень интересную идею ты подкинул, хочу ее поковырять.. Хотя все же склоняюсь в сторону того, что моб браузер не "шарит" в event.path[1].children[1]

Comment: `браузер не "шарит" в event.path[1].children[1]`   я еще могу понять, что в каком то браузере не работает, но не во всех же...

Comment: @De.Minov к вопросу добавил HTML, там все прагматично)

Comment: @Air, тестирую в последнем моб сафари и последнем моб Хроме, не работает

Comment: Может нужны `touch` события, а не `click`..

Comment: Некоторые браузеры на мобилках использую `click` при нажатии, но сафари использует `touch`, по этому воспользуйтесь советом [@Rudi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1421093/#comment2530781_1421093), добавьте ивент и для `touch`.

Comment: а зачем `path` вообще?

Comment: @Grundy ну я вывел в консоль содержимое всего объекта и посмотрел как дотянуться до необходимого детеныша)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.path` является нестандартным, не во всех браузерах поддерживается.

Рекомендуется использовать https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath

ну или проверять его наличие

```
const path = event.path || (event.composedPath && event.composedPath());
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Решение апдейтнул в вопросе!!)